# SQL Tranformations in view or stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view, powerbi, azure-synapse

I am working with one database where the transformations- all joins, case statements, adding new column happens in the view. I am unable to find a definite answer on how doing this in the view compared to stored procedures and having all the data ready as needed stored in the underlying table would perform?

Is it a best practice to do such complex joins and have a whole bunch of transformation code actually residing in the views?

This view is later read by Power BI.

Database is in Azure SQL DW dedicated SQL pool.

Appreciate any links to reading or if you have an answer to that please share. Thanks.

Comment: View vs procedures isn't really any different, more a question of modularization. Joins vs denormalization: all things being equal you should keep it normalized and do joins, but it's common in data warehousing to just denormalize. Either way, this is opinion based and not really answerable.

Comment: You should not use views that contain/do complex transformations. It would be considered best practice to do the transformations to a defined table, then read from that table into Power BI, reads will be quicker from the table, performance would be better